# Reading from a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to read from a CSV file in Python but I can't find any good online solution.

This is my code so far:

```
import csv

def defTakeOrder():
    listAvailable = []
    listOrder = input("Type your order in the format:\n'GTIN-8,Quantity...' repeated as necessary.\n If the quanitity is 1, still enter a 1 rather than leaving the space blank.\n")
    listOrder = listOrder.split(",")
    fileExcel = csv.reader(open("C:\Users\Sean\Documents\Year 12\CS\Summer\Book1.csv", newline = ""), delimiter=" ", quotechar="|")
    for i in fileExcel:
        listAvailable.append(i)
    print(listAvailable)


defTakeOrder()
```

Can someone help me with the code to read from this?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Sorry, but what on earth caused all these downvotes? I'm trying to productively work and this has blocked me from asking for a couple of days, which means I now can't work as efficiently. Can someone explain if there's a rule I'm breaking or something?

Comment: On first glance, that code *does* read a csv and put it in a list. Is something specific broken?

Comment: so, what's wrong with your approach, what does it do, what does it not do, what did you expect, where's the problem with what's happening, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors on the first bracket in "fileExcel = (..." and on the second quotemark in "delimiter = " ""

Comment: @SeanOTRS you have a misplaced `)` hence the syntax errors

Comment: @Aaron where is this misplaced `)`?

Comment: @SeanOTRS nvm, I lied... I thought newline kwd wanted to be part of `csv.reader` rather than `open`. I was wrong..

Comment: @SeanOTRS post more of the error message you're getting. There's nothing inherently wrong with what you have shown that would throw an exception (hence down-votes for poorly defined question). We can't help if we don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to import anything to read a CSV. This code will read a CSV and create a list. Each element of the list will be a list that is a row, and each element of each sublist will be an item in the CSV, since `row.split` will return a list.

```
file = "C:\Users\Sean\Documents\Year 12\CS\Summer\Book1.csv"    
csv = []
with open(file, "r") as text:
    for row in text:
        csv.append(row.split(","))
```

Comment: Your parsing fails on a row containing `1,2,3,"This is the 4th column, and it has a comma.",5`. This is a valid CSV row, and this kind of stuff is a good reason to not write your own parsers whenever you can avoid it. The OP doesn't seem to want to read from an actual file, anyway.

Comment: I do need to read from an actual file, it is a mockup of a product database. What do you mean by not writing your own parsers? I'm a little confused.

Comment: @SeanOTRS I mean that when storing data in text format and reading from it, you should *very strongly* favor using existing, well known standards and existing, well tested libraries for those standard formats. The "parser" in this answer is the `row.split(","))`, which uses raw text operations to attempt to parse the row into individual columns. My example above demonstrates that the attempt is broken on standard, well formed CSV data. Most standard formats have escaping mechanisms to allow you use the characters the format considers special, and simplistic attempts like this break on them.